# Do I need to export LLVM along with my compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I'm writing a compiler in C++ for my new programming language with LLVM as the back-end.  Currently I have LLVM installed in my computer, when I build the executable of the compiler and pass as input a program, the compiler generates the IR of the program and I can run it or even generate the binary file  of the program with LLVM's command line tools like `lli`.  Suppose I would like to export the compiler executable so other computers can start using it even if they don't have LLVM installed. How do I get them to use the compiler without having to worry about having LLVM installed?

(Note that I don't use any build system like `cmake` or `gnu-make` for the moment)

Comment: Welcome to SO! So, you want other computers to use the compiler (and its required executables) without already having the compiler installed? Bite an apple, but without apple? I don't understand...

Comment: @Ripi2 , I want to export the compiler front-end (the part of the compiler which scans, parses and translates the initial code source to the LLVM IR) and back-end (the LLVM infrastructure, the part that generates the binary executable using the IR) together. But I don't want other computers to worry about having LLVM (the back-end) installed as it is a separate part. Now the question is: Do I need to include LLVM's binary files along with the compiler front-end?

Comment: I definitely believe it's possible to link everything you need from LLVM directly into your custom compiler binary, though I am not aware of the detailed steps required.

Comment: You need LLVM required binary files. And know how to call them, and in what order, and their parameters. I don't see how different (apart form avoiding unrequired files) is this from installing LLVM.